# Devise + Cancan cause a redirection loop in production but not in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, cancancan

I have had Devise working in my rails4 app for quite some time already. Now I had a need to add different roles decided to use Cancan to accomplish this.

Everything was working just fine in development but when I deployed code to production all I got was infinite redirect loop. If I delete cookies I can get login page but signing in ends in the same loop.

My root redirects to controllers index action.

I have basically only one controller with any business logic and my root redirects to index action in this controller.

Related lines from the controller.

```
load_and_authorize_resource
skip_authorization_check :only => [:index]
```

But I have also tried this:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

And in addition previous appended with both of these (separately)

```
:except => [:index]
:unless => :devise_controller?
```

In ApplicationController I have both all of these together and separately

```
check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
before_filter :authenticate_user!,  :unless => :devise_controller?
```

And both of these I have tried with and without that unless statement.

I tried following relevant wikis to the letter but can't seem to get this working in production. If it makes any difference I am using Nginx/Passenger combo in production.

While writing this I realized that I have been using Cancan 1.6, I haven't tried Cancancan yet. Will give it a go next.

All help is appreaciated.

**UPDATE**: I tried this with Cancancan 1.9.2 (Instead of Cancan 1.6) with similar results. I have for the time being disabled it until I find a solution or alternative authorization gem.

Comment: Minor aside - new gem CanCanCan (maintained) which can be used to replace no longer maintained CanCan- Pierre

Comment: Yes, noticed that while writing my question. Will try that later tonight to see if it makes a difference.